# realm with rxjava - flexibility of using other handler threads than UI thread?

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

After reading Realm's doc (which is pretty good, thumbs up for that), here is what comes to my mind so far:

1. realm requires a handler thread to operate, and the UI thread would be perfect
2. if you don't want to slow down UI thread by querying in UI thread, you can use `findAllAsync()` or other similar methods, which executes the query off UI thread and carry the results back to UI thread

Now my problem is more than "I don't want to query in UI thread". I want to be able to query realm in a handler thread I created, chain the result `Observable` with other processor `Observable`s running on the same handler thread, and finally deliver the processing result to UI thread. Mainly because the processing is too expensive for UI thread.

Basically a snippet of such will look something like this:

```
Observable
    .defer(new Func0<Observable<RealmResults<User>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RealmResults<User>> call() {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            return realm.where(User.class).findAll().asObservable();
        }
    })
    .map(new Func1<RealmResults<User>, UserUIData>() {
        @Override
        public UserUIData call(RealmResults<User> users) {
            return new UserUIData(users.first());
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(MY_HANDLER_THREAD_SCHEDULER)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();
```

Two problems I've encountered so far:

1. when I unsubscribe from UI thread the app would crash because according to `RealmObservableFactory`, the change listener will have to be removed *in UI thread* when unsubscribed. Seems to me that we can't change on which scheduler the following will be executed, plus Realm doesn't allow access/modify across threads, hence the crash.

   ```
   subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() {
       @Override
       public void call() {
           realm.removeChangeListener(listener);
       }
   }));
   ```
2. I cannot find a way to properly close the `Realm` instance.

Could anyone please help point me to the correct direction on this? Am I not supposed to do this in the first place? Is there a better way?

Many thanks.

Comment: my short-gap solution for problem 1 is to, upon unsubscribed, post a runnable in the intended handler thread and remove the listener from there. as for problem 2, i currently leave the db instance unclosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a combination of `unsubscribeOn`/`doOnUnsubscribe` like this (not tested):

```
AtomReference<Realm> realmRef = new AtomicReference(null);
Observable
    .defer(new Func0<Observable<RealmResults<User>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<RealmResults<User>> call() {
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realmRef.set(realm);
            return realm.where(User.class).findAll().asObservable();
        }
    })
    // ...
    .doOnOnsubscribe(realmRef.get().close())
    .unsubscribeOn(MY_HANDLER_THREAD_SCHEDULER)
    .subscribeOn(MY_HANDLER_THREAD_SCHEDULER)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();
```

We have an issue here for making it easier to move RealmQueries across threads. Once that is implemented this case should be better handled: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1955

Comment: thanks for pointing out `unsubscribeOn()`, this is definitely the cleaner way to go.